# Automatic discount for membership not working

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

Using D7/CiviCRM 4.6.10 and Cividiscount 3.1

I've set up a discount code to enable current members to renew their membership at 50% of the standard membership fee. If i make the code non-automatic and enter it manually it works.

Setting the automatic discount options for the code for the membership type and 'any current status' should ensure that if the user has the membership type and their status is one of the those considered current (i.e. New, Current, Grace) then they automatically get the discount, but I'm seeing nothing applied on the contribution page.

The contribution page recognises the user as a current member, as it is displaying a message to tell the user when their current membership is due to expire, but it is not applying the discount, and nor it it displaying the "not eligible" message.

Is this a known issue, or am I missing something subtle in the configuration?

Comment: I don't think you've missed anything, probably worth reporting on https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount. Can see some similar issues on the issue queue but not the exact same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research shows that this is indeed a known issue for this version of CiviCRM: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17388 states that it has been fixed for version 4.7. That version is only in beta at the time of writing, so not of help on a production site. I wonder if this fix will be rolled into 4.6.x given that 4.6 is the new LTS (long term support) version?

Answer (score 1):

Graham, I found the fix here
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17388

We had exactly the same issue but really thankful it is resolved with the patch

Jon-man

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied the changes to cividiscount.php as outlined from these issues?

https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/120